# php spreadsheet getWidth return -1.0

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I am using Laravel-excel in a Laravel project, and I need to export an excel with an image centered in B1, and because I needed other stylings I used `WithEvents`, and inside the `registerEvents()` function I try to get the column width of `B` as follow `$event->sheet->getDelegate()->getColumnDimension('B')->getWidth()`, but I get -1.0 in return which is not correct, also I used auto width columns because I needed that as follow:

```
foreach($event->sheet->getDelegate()->getColumnIterator() as $col)
{
  $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getColumnDimension($col->getColumnIndex())->setAutoSize(true);
 }
```

**Note:** `$event->sheet->getDelegate()` will return active sheet which is equal to `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()`

Answer (score 0):

The -1 is the value for the demention of auto with size. If you will work with it you must have something like

```
$autowith = sheet->getDelegate()->getColumnDimension($col->getColumnIndex());
$calc=5
if($autowith == -1){
   $calc += 22.2;
}else{
   $calc += $autowith;
}
```